# Постановка дефиса

Tags: раздельно-дефис

Здравствуйте. Нужна ли постановка дефиса после обозначения химического элемента перед прилагательным или существительным 40Ar/39Ar геохронологических исследований/40Ar/39Ar датировки?

Answer (score 1):

В научной литературе таких дефисов нет.Например:"Интерпретация спектров 
39Ar-40Ar возрастов, преимущества, недостатки 39Ar-40Ar метода изотопного датирования"     
http://wiki.web.ru/wiki/

Латиница с кириллицей не соединяются дефисом.